# How to use jQuery to find a certain string within a div, and then apply specific styles to another div if it exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, search

Okay, so say I had a HTML page as follows:

```
 <html>
    <div>
       <div id='header'>Page Title</div>
       <div id='content'> Main content here </div>
       <div id='meta'> 
          <a href='#'>Hello</a> 
          <a href='#'>Link 2</a>
          <a href='#'>Link 3</a>
       </div>
    </div>
  </html>
```

What I want to create is a function the basically searches the `meta` div  **(only this div)** to find an `a` link that contains the string `Hello`, for this examples purposes. 
 
 If the `Hello` string exists, a CSS style of `background: red;` should be applied to the `header` div (overwriting any existing background styles on the `header` div.) 
 
 I would like to use JavaScript/jQuery to do this. Any suggestions on how this could be achieved? (Sorry if that was confusing)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, they all seem to work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if($("#meta a:contains('Hello')").length > 0){
    $("#header").css("background", "red");
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/dB66L/

[:contains Selector Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: This is the simplest, best answer

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if ($('#meta:has(a:contains("Hello"))').length > 0) {
    $('#header').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7g4DF/)</kbd>

---

References

[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

[:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

With strict text comparison:

```
$('#header').filter(function() {
    return $('#meta a').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'Hello';
    }).length;
}).css('background', '#f00');
```

Without strict text comparison:

```
$('#header').filter(function() {
    return $('#meta a:contains("Hello")').length;
}).css('background', 'red');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/X6vmA/